# Deleting all elements in a list where the output of elements from a function is zero

Tags: list-manipulation, code-request, broken-code

I tried using `DeleteCases` to delete elements in `r1` where `g2==0` to get a defined arithmetic mean for `T`.

```
\[Psi] = Sqrt[2] - 1;
\[Epsilon] = 0.001;
w = 40000;
f[\[Omega]_] := 
  N[Mean[Select[
     Flatten[Table[(Ceiling[n (\[Psi] - \[Epsilon])] + a)/n, {a, 1, 
        1000}, {n, 1, Round[(\[Omega])/(2^a)]}]], 
     Between[#, {\[Psi] - \[Epsilon], \[Psi] + \[Epsilon]}] &]]];
g1[x_] := (Max[Abs[f[x + 1] - f[x + 2]], Abs[f[x] - f[x + 1]]]);
g2[x_] := (Min[Abs[f[x + 1] - f[x + 2]], Abs[f[x] - f[x + 1]]]);
r1 = DeleteCases[Flatten[Table[x, {x, 1, w}]], g2[#] == 0 &];
T = N[Mean[Table[g1[x]/g2[x], {x, r1}]]]
```

Instead, I get an error of division by zero.

How do we delete all elements in `r1` where `g2==0` to get defined arithmetic mean for `T`?

Comment: The syntax used for `DeleteCases` in the definition of `r1` is wrong. From the documentation, the proper syntax is `DeleteCases[expr, pattern]`, but `g2[#] == 0&` is **not** a pattern. The pattern would be `_?(g2[#] == 0&)`. Calculation of `g2` is slow. To prevent calculating `g2` more than once for a given value, use memorization, i.e., `g2[x_] := g2[x] = ...` For a `minimal working example` do not use such large values of `w`.

Comment: @BobHanlon Thanks! Is it possible to put this in your answer. I will award you with 15 points.

Comment: @BobHanlon However... I'd like to know if my average converges for larger values. How do we do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Clear["Global`*"]

ψ = Sqrt[2] - 1;
ϵ = 0.001;
```

I have used a smaller value of `w` to reduce the time required to evaluate. After you have finalized the code, increase `w` to whatever required value.

```
w = 4000;
```

To improve efficiency, use memorization for `f` and `g2`

```
f[ω_] := f[ω] =
   N[Mean[
     Select[
      Flatten[
       Table[(Ceiling[n (ψ - ϵ)] + a)/n, {a, 1, 1000}, {n, 1, 
         Round[(ω)/(2^a)]}]], 
      Between[#, {ψ - ϵ, ψ + ϵ}] &]]];
g1[x_] := (Max[Abs[f[x + 1] - f[x + 2]], Abs[f[x] - f[x + 1]]]);
g2[x_] := g2[x] =
   (Min[Abs[f[x + 1] - f[x + 2]], Abs[f[x] - f[x + 1]]]);
```

For some values of `x`, `g2` does not evaluate to a number.

```
{g2[1024], g2[1025]}

(* {Min[0, Abs[-0.415205 + Mean[{}]]], 
    Min[0., Abs[-0.415205 + Mean[{}]]]} *)
```

You need to determine why this occurs. I will just delete those cases as well as when `g2[x] == 0`

```
r1 = DeleteCases[
   Flatten[Table[x, {x, 1, w}]], _?(g2[#] == 0 || ! NumericQ[g2[#]] &)];

Length@r1

(* 565 *)

T = N[Mean[Table[g1[x]/g2[x], {x, r1}]]]

(* 8.05429 *)
```